# Error when creating controller in Episerver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver

I'm trying to create a block in Episerver but got an error for the name of my class in the controller. The errormessage is

> The type 'MyEpiserverSite.Controllers.WeekletterController' cannot be used as type parameter 'TBlockData' in the generic type or method 'BlockController'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyEpiserverSite.Controllers.WeekletterController' to'EPIServer.Core.BlockData'

My code is

```
using EPiServer.Web.Mvc;
using EpiserverSite1.Models.Blocks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyEpiserverSite.Controllers
{
    public class WeekletterController : BlockController<WeekletterController>
 {
    public override ActionResult Index(WeekletterBlock currentblock)
    {
        return PartialView(currentblock);
    }
 }
}
```

Is there any using that I am missing or what are wrong whit my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inherit from `BlockController<WeekletterController>` but you should inherit from `BlockController<WeekletterBlock>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid controllers for blocks, unless they are really necessary, i.e. you need to have business logic between the block data and the view.

Comment: What benefits are there in avoiding controllers for blocks?